# tailwindcss couldn't set margin for medium device

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Here I am trying to give two separate margins for two separate screen sizes, one will be a medium screen(18-inch monitor) and another will be a large screen(21-inch monitor). My **`md:mx-[400px]`** margins not applying

my css code here

```
  <div className='story_section bg-white mt-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg md:mx-[400px] lg:mx-[600px]'>
```

my `lg:mx-[600-px]` working but why not working `md:mx-[400px]` when change screen size ? see the two screenshot

**18 inch monitor**
[image]

**21 inch monitor**
[image]

Comment: is the webpack running as expected?

Comment: @Alopwer I don't understand. Can I please explain

Comment: Can you share your tailwind config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are using tailwindcss v3.3.3 with default breakpoints on your project, by using these rules `md:mx-[400px] lg:mx-[600px]`, you do not cover mobile and the `sm` breakpoint.

If you want a default `mx` of 400px and a `mx` of 600px at `lg` breakpoint and larger, you should use : `mx-[400px] lg:mx-[600px]`.

See the [targeting mobile screens](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-mobile-screens) part of the documentation. You might be in a similar case with `lg` breakpoint.